# Parse Social Login without PFUtils

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I am using parse for my app's backend, and I need to include social logins. I will be using log in with Twitter and the new Twitter Digits.

What is the best way to create a new user in Parse via social logins without using their PFUtils wrappers to handle the username/password.

What do I supply to parse for the username and password for a new user?

I will be storing the approrpriare OAuth tokens locally in keychain myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly what you asked for but I have implemented a way to authenticate with Twitter Digits to login with Parse, you can view the code here: https://github.com/felix-dumit/PFUser-Digits

Comment: That’s the temporary solution I’m going with, is there any more robust solution that you could come up with though?

Comment: as far as I know you need an username and password to successfully signup, which is my in my code I had to create random usernames and passwords. You could store the tokens locally like you said and after the first login you just call `[PFUser become:token]`

Comment: Ohh alright that's clever. I will implement it like you suggested. Thanks you!